# Wordpress search - Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

Tags: php, wordpress, search, error-handling

I have start to experience a issue in a project that is based on wordpress. The issue is pretty weird.

Here is the description: when I search anything that doesn't start with the letter `d` on the website it works fine - but when searching anything starting with the letter `d` i get this `Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)`.

I have been searching a lot about, but can't find anything related. I have even remade the search code from scratch using wordpress query class and still didn't work.

It happens to me in all the browsers so i don't think that this is a browser related issue. I have also tried the search in several other networks and even changed a few settings on my router, but no success.

The url for the website is: http://www.estanaweb.com.br/

The most used search term that most users try and fail is "dudalina", heres the url: http://www.estanaweb.com.br/?s=dudalina, if i try searching only for "udalina" it works fine.

Comment: I'm in Spain, your site doesn't even load. Could be very well a server issue.

Comment: Looks to be your back-end code rather than the front-end, considering that hitting http://www.estanaweb.com.br/?s=dudalina with a wget seems to hang infinitely. Maybe there's something odd in your database that's causing the search to fail in a nasty way... Is there anything in your server error logs?

Comment: Thanks guys, i got it to work with M8R-1jmw5r's hint right bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to your problem is very easy, you only need to add the space character in front of the search-term. Wordpress will remove it for the search so you actually search the same as without but you won't get the timeout issue.

Try it your own:

- [`http://www.estanaweb.com.br/?s=%20dudalina`](http://www.estanaweb.com.br/?s=%20dudalina)

For a hotfix I suggest you place a rewrite rule into your server configuration that does  automatically and transparently add a space character here.

BTW, for me the original error I got in the browser was:

> Error 103 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED): Unknown error.

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Thank you very much. It really didn't come to mind to try adding a empty space before the query. For now i fixed it by adding a jquery code to prepend a empty space before the search field value when submitting the form. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, this is total patchwork. Keep in mind that users having scripts disabled might run into that problem again. So better check with your server-setting what is going on there. This somewhat smells like an endless loop and is possible remotely exploitable.

Comment: Yes, i'm working on a hotfix through the .htaccess as you recommended. Thanks again!